# Jquery clone and remove div

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I have implemented jquery clone and remove. When **ADD** button is clicked a **DIV A** with certain form elements are cloned and inserted into another **DIV B**. In **DIV A** there is a hidden form button **REMOVE**. Now I require to enable the REMOVE button only in the clones when ADD button is clicked. i.e; I want to keep the form element in **DIV A** always hidden.

This is my code.

```
<div class="rule" id="rule">                        
            <div class="fm-req">
                <select name="rulefield" id="rulefield">
                    <option value="">select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="fm-opt" >
                <input type="button" class='remove' value="-" style="display:none;"/>
            </div>
        </div>                  
    <div class="fm-rulebutton">
        <input type="button" id="addButton "class='add' value="+"/>
    </div>

        <div id='TextBoxesGroup' class="group">
```

here **Div 'rule'** is cloned into **Div 'TextBoxesGroup'**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = 0;
    $('.add').click(function(){
            id++;
            $('.fm-opt').children('.remove').show();
            var prot = $(document).find(".rule").clone();
            prot.attr("class", 'rule'+id)
            prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);

            $(document).find("div .group").append(prot);
    });        


    $('.remove').live("click", function(){
            $(this).closest("#rule").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess this line is refering to something we don't see in your code: `prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);`. Also I see that you keep always the same id but change the class and this is not correct. IDs should be unique while CLASSs can be the same for multiple elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `.show()` for all remove buttons. You need to limit it to only the new clone element. Like so:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    id++;
    var prot = $(document).find(".rule").clone();
    prot.attr("class", 'rule'+id)
    prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);
    prot.find('input.remove').show();//<-- this is the important part

    $(document).find("div .group").append(prot);
});
```

This code will now only call `.show()` on the remove button that is found within the newly cloned element

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.add').click(function(){
            id++;
            $('.fm-opt').children('.remove').show();
            var prot = $(document).find(".rule").clone();
            prot.attr("class", 'rule'+id)
            prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);

            $(document).find("div .group").append(prot);
    });
```

should be changed as,

```
$('.add').click(function(){
            id++;
            var prot = $(document).find(".rule").clone();
            prot.attr("class", 'rule'+id)
            prot.children('.remove').show();
            prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);
            $(document).find("div .group").append(prot);
    });
```

You should make visible only those buttons  which have been cloned.

Answer (score 0):

While cloning add unique Id="" value for cloned element.

In remove method, you can easily access the unique element and remove it.

Comment: This isn't what the question is. The OP wants to know how to keep the "Remove" button in the first element hidden, and only show it for clones (I think)